# security for bundle resources

Tags: ios

I have an app to present some confidential documents which store as bundle resources. My concern is that someone with a jailbroken device can access the bundle resources directly. Is there any way to encrypt the bundle resources and protect them?

Comment: Can your users simply aim a camera at the screen? Or use the screenshot shortcut? Are you sure you're solving a problem that needs to be solved?

Comment: Are you sure you want to send the documents to the device at all, if you don't trust your users?

Comment: The app will go to app store. But we just want authorized user to access it. The app need to be activated for the first time. But I think someone can download the app and access the content bypass the activation.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, I would pull the data from a server after activation. Barring that (if it were a large amount of data), I would encrypt the data against a random key, and then provide that key to the application during activation. The main point is that you don't want to provide the unencrypted data to a user you don't want to have it.