# SwiftUI App make CSV file encrypted / unreadable in bundle

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, bundle

I have a swiftUI app and it reads from and writes to a CSV file called sythesisedData.csv. Part of this project is trying to have a level of user-privacy, and therefore I want this CSV file to be unreadable if anyone were to try and directly open it from the application bundle.

I have tried doing this (n.b fileUrl points to the synthesisedData.csv file)

```
    try (fileUrl as NSURL).setResourceValue(
                         URLFileProtection.complete,
            forKey: .fileProtectionKey)
```

But the file when I inspect the bundle in the finder of my Mac is still readable in plain text. I find the csv file by doing `.app file -> show package contents -> open the .csv file`.

Does anyone know how to make this file unreadable when opened manually? Obviously my app still needs to be able to read and write from it though.

P.S this file is NOT created by my app, it pre-exists before the app is launched as it is populated with data I need.

Comment: There are a few misunderstandings here. 1) This isn't specific to SwiftUI at all -- SwiftUI is a framework for displaying UI. 2) Using `setResourceValue` won't do anything to a file in your bundle, which is just copied by the system at compile time -- not at runtime when the code is run. 3) "read and write from it" -- your app cannot write to a file in the bundle, but it can write to a file in your documents directory, temp, etc

Comment: @jnpdx I'm not really sure how to re-format the question to make it accurate then. Do you understand what I'm trying to say? That the initial file which was dragged and dropped into the project has to be protected if anyone wants to manually open this file, and that I guess any subsequent temp files which are made from this data also need to be protected / unreadable. This is my first attempt at iOS dev ever, so please forgive if the terminology or understanding is not accurate.

Comment: Yes, I do understand. Basically, you need a way to encrypt/decrypt files while reading/writing in Swift. Not my area of expertise, otherwise I'd answer. My comment was just to provide some insight about the path that you're going to end up having to take (eg not trying to set in code a way to encrypt a bundle file, the fact that this isn't a SwiftUI issue at all, etc). Good luck!

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks for the corrections anyway, should help my understanding. Have removed the SwiftUI tag to stop any further confusions there. Thanks!

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [security for bundle resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025263/security-for-bundle-resources)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encrypt your file using wrapper like: https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor
and then write the file to the document directory.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I ended up doing :)